# How to install php7 modules on docker official php7.1-apache image?

Tags: dockerfile, xdebug, php-7.1

I am using the official php:7.1-apache docker image. I want to install a bunch of modules such as xdebug. However, I cannot. I use apt-get but I get the response: `E: Unable to locate package php7.0-xdebug`

What am I missing? Why is it so nearly impossible to add any php7 add-ons to this official base image through apt-get? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The correct package is `php-xdebug`:

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y php-xdebug
```

Ensure to run it after php is installed properly.

If you sill get the error apt-get need to know the debian repository.
Add this lies BEFORE installing xdebug:

```
RUN  echo "deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN  echo "deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```